# Win 10: how to select which drive to boot from

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

Laptop has two hard drives: the original spinning drive and a new NVMe M.2 SSD.  The new SSD has a fresh install of Windows 10 v1909.  The Win 10 version on the spinning drive is earlier than that (v18xx or v1903 - not sure which).  Both drives are partitioned GPT and the BIOS is set for UEFI.

The laptop is currently working well - it is booting from the NVMe SSD **very** quickly.

However, I would like the option to boot into the original OS located on the spinning drive.  This will let me go back to the previous Windows installation to see which programs I have yet to install on the new drive.

I'm looking for options to allow me to select which drive to boot from.  I've looked at something called "Super GRUB2" but would like advice before I do something that will cause me a lot of pain.

I expect this will be temporary - I don't anticipate a need to go back to the (painfully) slow spinning drive OS once I have everything moved over to the new OS.

Comment: Is there a function key, e.g. <kbd>F9</kbd>, to select boot device at startup?

Comment: Start > run > msconfig. Everything you need is in there.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Yes, there is.  I use that whenever I need to boot from a USB key.  However, it never occurred to me that it might allow me to select between internal hard drives.  I will check this afternoon to see if that might work.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: Your suggestion worked perfectly.  Please create an answer with that information so that I can accept it.

Comment: @DwayneReid, glad it helped... added enough info to call it an "answer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some PC's have two (or more) different function keys controlling bootup. For example, on one laptop, <kbd>F2</kbd> accesses BIOS/UEFI setup (which often includes *permanent* changes to boot device order), while <kbd>F9</kbd> accesses a short menu with a list of currently identified bootable devices.

Check for the correct key on your PC. Of course, many boot so rapidly that the key needs to be held from *before* stating bootup.

BTW, this is helpful when imaging a system, since no change to BIOS/UEFI setup is needed to select a bootable USB flash drive with dd, Macrium Reflect, etc.